# MVC 4 Changing a field based on DropDownListFor selection

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a form that has a dropdownlist that is made up of different course names and a textbox that will contain the number of the next course section based on the dropdown selection and its highest existing section number in the database. After a selection is made the javascript will get called, then call my controller method to figure out which section number it should be, and then fill the textbox.

My dropdownlist: Controller

```
ViewBag.CourseList = new SelectList(db.CourseLists, "CourseTitle", "CourseTitle");
```

My dropdownlist: View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CourseTitle,
                new SelectList(@ViewBag.CourseList, "Value", "Text"), " -- Select Course -- ", new { @id = "CourseTitle", onchange = "CourseChange()" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseTitle)
```

Textbox:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClassNumber, new { @id = "ClassNumber" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassNumber)
```

Javascript functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function CourseChange() {
      var courseTitle = $('#CourseTitle').val(); //Is always null
      $.getJSON("NextClassNumber", courseTitle, updateClassNumber);
  };

  updateClassNumber = function (data) {
      $('#ClassNumber').val(data);
  };
</script>
```

When I make a change my method in my controller is called and passes back a value and sets my textbox, but the value for the selected item is coming through as null.  Any ideas as to why?

::::EDIT::::

```
@model QIEducationWebApp.Models.Course

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add New Course";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#CourseTitle').on('change', function () {
            var courseTitle = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action="NextClassNumber", controller="Course"})',
                data: { courseTitle: courseTitle },
                type: 'get'
            }).done(function (data) {
                $('#ClassNumber').val(data);
            });
        });
    });

</script>

<h1 class="page-header">@ViewBag.Title</h1>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th class="table-row">
                Course Title:
            </th>
            <td class="table-row">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CourseTitle1,
                    @ViewBag.CourseList as SelectList, " -- Select Course -- ", new { @class="form-control", @id="CourseTitle" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseTitle)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-row">
                Class Number:
            </th>
            <td class="table-row">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClassNumber, new { @id = "ClassNumber" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassNumber)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-row">
                Course Type:
            </th>
            <td class="table-row">
                @Html.DropDownList("CourseType", " -- Select Type -- ")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseType)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-row">
                Start & End Date:
            </th>
            <td class="table-row">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CourseStartDate)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseStartDate)
            </td>
            <td class="table-row">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CourseEndDate)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseEndDate)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td class="table-row-blank"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="table-row-button">
                <input class="button" type="submit" value="Create" />
                <input type="button" class="button" value="Cancel" 
                    onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index")'" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should work fine if the select list is being generated correctly.

I would use part of the suggestion above and use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CourseTitle,
            (SelectList)ViewBag.CourseList,
            " -- Select Course -- ",
            new { onchange = "CourseChange()" })
```

using another good suggestion already mentioned you can change your script to use `on` instead

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#CourseTitle').on('change', function () {
            var courseTitle = $(this).val();
            $.getJSON("NextClassNumber", courseTitle, function (data) {
                $('#ClassNumber').val(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

here is a dotnetfiddle example.  [**DotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7rojMI)

Comment: I have tried to use the on as well, but it doesn't call the javascript when a selection is made

Comment: Alright, So I have the it working to replace the text in the textbox.  But the submit button on the form isn't responding.  All of the fields are filled in like they were before, but you click it and it does nothing.  Originally I had the drop down and then the user would specify the class number and the button worked for this.

Comment: make sure the button is type submit  `<input type="submit" value="Submit" />` or `<button type="submit">Submit</button>` and that it is inside your `<form></form>`

Comment: Added the entire view to the post

Comment: It looks fine.. could be a validation error that you cant see.  Change your validationsummary to `@Html.ValidationSummary(false)`  If that's not it, then you might want to install something like Fiddler to see where the data is trying to post to.

Comment: Figured it out.  Creating the dropdown i have `model => model.CourseTitle1,` which is the intermitant value for coursetitle being linked to another table, istead of `model => model.CourseTitle,` which is for the actual column in course.  Thank you for everything!

Comment: I have another question out that is similar to this one if you wanna take it look.  [Other Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31192524/mvc-4-changing-multiple-display-fields-based-on-dropdownlistfor-selection)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass reference of dropdownlist from the onchange event :

```
onchange = "CourseChange"
```

and in js function:

```
function CourseChange(element) {

    var selected = element.Value;
    // or
    var selected = $(element).val();
```

and a side note you don't need to construct `SelectList` again on View just cast it from ViewBag:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CourseTitle,
                      @ViewBag.CourseList as SelectList,
                      "-- Select Course --",
                      new { onchange = "CourseChange" })
```

Comment: `this` is always implicitly passed. The problem here is that the user is setting the onchange handler to an actual call to `CourseChange()`, which doesn't allow JavaScript to pass anything. set the onchange to just `CourseChange`, without deferencing the function, or better yet, use an unobstrusive event handler, like `$('#whatever').on('change', CourseChange);`.

Comment: So when I try to do it this way, as well as the answer below here, the javascript function doesn't seem to get called, or my controller method doesn't get called.  It's not hitting breakpoints in the controller and isn't changing the field to a default parameter.    

`function CourseChange(element) {
        var courseTitle = $(element).val();
        $.getJSON("NextClassNumber", courseTitle, function(data) {
            $('#ClassNumber').val(data);
        });
    };`
  and `onchange = "CourseChange" `