# MVC 4 Changing multiple display fields based on DropDownListFor selection

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

[MVC 4 Changing a field based on DropDownListFor selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31166459/mvc-4-changing-a-field-based-on-dropdownlistfor-selection)

First off, almost the same as the above question, but the solution isn't working for this one.

I have a page that will hold a dropdown list.  after selection it will change the display fields based off the selection.

The javascript in the view is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#courseName').on('change', function () {
            var courseID = $(this).val();
            var studentID = '@ViewBag.StudentID';
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("FillCourseInfo", "Student")',
                data: {StudentID: studentID, CourseID: courseID},
                type: 'get'
            }).done(function(data){
                $('#courseStartDate').text(data.courseStartDate); 
                $('#courseEndDate').text(data.courseEndDate);
                $('#projectName').text(data.projectName);
                $('#graduated').text(data.graduated);
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

The view:

```
<tr>
            <th class="table-row">
                Course Title:
            </th>
            <td class="table-row">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.courseName,
                    @ViewBag.courseList as SelectList, " -- Select Course -- ",
                    new { @class = "form-control" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-row">
                Start & End Date:
            </th>
            <td class="table-row">
                <label id="#courseStartDate" class="form-control">@Model.courseStartDate</label>
            </td>
            <td class="table-row">
                <label id="#courseEndDate" class="form-control">@Model.courseEndDate</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-row">
                Project:
            </th>
            <td class="table-row">
                <label id="#projectName" class="form-control">@Model.projectName</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-row">
                Graduated:
            </th>
            <td class="table-row">
                <label id="#graduated">@Model.graduated</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

And the Controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult FillCourseInfo(int StudentID, int CourseID)
        {
            var ret = (from e in db.Enrollments 
                       join c in db.Courses on e.CourseID equals c.CourseID
                       where e.StudentID == StudentID && e.CourseID == CourseID
                       select new
                       {
                           courseStartDate = c.CourseStartDate,
                           courseEndDate = c.CourseEndDate,
                           projectName = e.Project.ProjectTitle,
                           graduated = e.Graduated

                       }).ToList()
                       .Select(a => new StudentCourseDetails() {
                           courseStartDate = a.courseStartDate.ToString("MMM d, yyyy"),
                           courseEndDate = a.courseEndDate.ToString("MMM d, yyyy"),
                           projectName = a.projectName,
                           graduated = a.graduated.Value.ToString()
                       }).FirstOrDefault();
            string sd = ret.courseStartDate;
            string ed = ret.courseEndDate;
            string pn = ret.projectName;
            string g = ret.graduated;
            return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

At the moment the javascript isn't getting hit or my method just isn't getting called.

Comment: Couple of quick questions - What is the `url` rendered in jquery? can you paste that? Also set the `contentType: 'application/json'` and give a try. HAndle error event and see what error you got.

Comment: if your drop list code is correct you need to use same case in your JQuery selector `$('#courseName').on('change', function () {`

Comment: If you literally mean just go from a `$('#CourseName')` to `$('#courseName')`, then that doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you are doing is not returning a single result from your `FillCourseInfo` action.

This means your json result is a list of `StudentCourseDetails`.  You would have to use `$('#Dates').val(data[0].courseDates);` to get your values.

Or if you're just expecting a single value you can use .FirstOrDefault() at the end of your linq query.

```
var ret = (from e in db.Enrollments 
               join c in db.Courses on e.CourseID equals c.CourseID
               where e.StudentID == StudentID && e.CourseID == CourseID
               select new StudentCourseDetails
               {
                   courseDates = c.CourseStartDate.ToString() + " " + c.CourseEndDate.ToString(),
                   projectName = e.Project.ProjectTitle,
                   graduated = e.Graduated

               }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I created another .NET Fiddle for you. [**DotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7rojMI)

To use ToString in your linq query, convert the result to a list, then build your json

```
 var ret = (from e in db.Enrollments
                   join c in db.Courses on e.CourseID equals c.CourseID
                   where e.StudentID == StudentID && e.CourseID == CourseID
                   select new
                   {
                       courseStartDate = c.CourseStartDate,
                       courseEndDate = c.CourseEndDate,
                       projectName = e.Project.ProjectTitle,
                       graduated = e.Graduated

                   }).ToList()
                   .Select(a => new StudentCourseDetails() {
                       courseDates = a.courseStartDate.ToString() + " " + a.courseEndDate.ToString(),
                       projectName = a.projectName,
                       graduated = a.graduated
                   }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: So, for some reason in your linq query you are allowed to use the .toString() and I am not.

Comment: that's because in my example it's selecting from `List<>` instead of `IEnumerable<>`

Comment: Yeah, noticed that.  So these fields won't need to be edited.  I have tried to use just the DisplayFor but that isn't working, nothing is coming up even though the script is running.  Is there another one to use that I am just missing?

Comment: will you need to pass the values back to your controller?

Comment: Nope.  Strictly for viewing the details of the course that a student took.  So select a course and display the values.  I mean i could disable the textboxes, but I think just a display without the text box is cleaner

Comment: you can just use labels  `<label id="#Dates">@Model.Dates</label>` then change your javascript to update the `text` instead of `val` `$('#Dates').text(data.courseDates);`

Comment: It doesn't like that the @Model.Dates etc. are null when loading the view.  Since they won't get a value until after a selection is made on the page

Comment: should be fine as long as you pass in an empty model when you load the view.  `return View(new ClassViewModel());` it's only complaining because your `@Model`is null

Comment: Alright, it is not complaining about the null model now, thank you.  But it isn't displaying the new values.  The javascript is running and the controller method is also running and collecting the needed values.

Comment: not real sure what you mean.. can you edit the DotNetFiddle above?

Comment: What I was trying to say is that the javascript and controller methods are being called when a selection is made, but the page text doesn't change. I was making changes to your DotNetFiddle to match as closely as I could to my code, but it was working in there.  I made edits to the post for the changes that I made in code.

Comment: add an error handler to your ajax call to make sure you're not getting an error with the request.  i added an example of this to the dotnetfiddle

Comment: Nope, not getting any errors, or at least nothing is popping up

Comment: take the `#` sign out of your label id's.. `<label id="#courseStartDate"` should be `<label id="courseStartDate"`  dont change your script though.. leave it like `$('#courseStartDate').text(data.courseStartDate);`

Comment: Yep.  That would be it.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help and patience.

Comment: I don't know if you would wanna look at another question of mine.  No one has yet to help as of yet.  [Here is the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31413356/mvc-4-updating-a-partial-view-from-another-partial-view-using-ajax-beginform)

Answer (score 0):

Change your Javascript function with below fuction:

```
$("#CourseName").change(function () {

            var courseID = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("FillCourseInfo","Student")', // we are calling json method
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { StudentID: @ViewBag.studentID, CourseID, courseID  },


                success: function (ret) {
            $('#Dates').val(ret.courseDates); 
                    $('#Project').val(ret.projectName);
                    $('#Graduated').val(ret.graduated);

                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    //alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
```

Change your controller function with below function

```
public JsonResult FillCourseInfo(int StudentID, int CourseID)
{
     var ret = (from e in db.Enrollments 
               join c in db.Courses on e.CourseID equals c.CourseID
               where e.StudentID == StudentID && e.CourseID == CourseID
               select new StudentCourseDetails
               {
                   courseDates = c.CourseStartDate.ToString() + " " + c.CourseEndDate.ToString(),
                   projectName = e.Project.ProjectTitle,
                   graduated = e.Graduated

               });
    return Json(ret);
}
```