# MVC 4 Updating a partial view from another partial view using Ajax.BeginForm()

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a comment section set up on one of my pages.  The parent view has a partial view which shows the comments for that ID and gives the option to display another partial view to post a comment.  When someone post a comment I want the first partial view within the parent to refresh displaying the new comment.

Currently when you click Post Comment, the AddComment method is called and added to the database.  I get an error saying that I am passing the wrong type of model to the view.  It seems to be trying to pass the return value to my AddComment partial view instead of injecting it into Partent View Div.

Parent View

```
@model QIEducationWebApp.Models.Course

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Course Details";
}

<h1 class="page-header">@ViewBag.Title</h1>


Javascript is here
.
.
.

<table class="table">

        DETAILS HERE

</table>


<ul id="view-options">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Back to Courses", "Index", "Course")</li>
</ul>

<input type="button" id="View" class="ShowComment" value="Show Comments"/>


<div id="CommentSection"/>
```

Partial View to view comments

```
Javascript is here
.
.
.

<div class="CommentSection">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="Comment">
            <div class="CommentText">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CommentText)
            </div>
            <div class="CommentSep">
                <span class="Commenter">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)</span> - <span class="CommentDate">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CommentDate)</span>
            </div> 
        </div>     
    }

    <input type="button" id="Post" class="AddComment" value="Add a Comment"/>
    <br />
    <br />
</div>

<div id="AddComment" />

    <br />
    <br />
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("ViewComments",
    new { courseID = @ViewBag.courseID, page }),
            PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(
                new PagedListRenderOptions { MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay = 5, DisplayLinkToFirstPage = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded, 
                DisplayLinkToLastPage = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded },
                new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "CommentSection" }))
```

Method behind the is partial view

```
public PartialViewResult ViewComments(int courseID, int? page = 1)
        {
            ViewBag.courseID = courseID;
            var coursecomments = db.CourseComments.Where(cc => cc.CourseID == courseID);
            int pageSize = 10;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return PartialView(coursecomments.OrderByDescending(cc => cc.CommentDate).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
```

Partial to Post Comment

```
Javascript is here
.
.
.

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddComment", "CourseComment", new { courseID = @ViewBag.courseID, userName = @User.Identity.Name },
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "CommentSection" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="NewComment">
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.CommentText, new { maxLength = 500 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CommentText)
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="PostComment" value="Post Comment" />
        <div id="Counter" class="CommentCounter"/>
    </div>


}
```

Controller method linked to the Post Comment Ajax.BeginForm()

```
public PartialViewResult AddComment(CourseComment coursecomment, int courseID, String userName)
{
    coursecomment.CommentDate = System.DateTime.Now;
    coursecomment.CourseID = courseID;
    coursecomment.UserName = userName;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.CourseComments.AddObject(coursecomment);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    ViewBag.courseID = courseID;
    return ViewComments(courseID);

}
```

Adding pictures

Details

[image]

After selecting View Comments button

[image]

After selecting Add Comment

[image]

After Posting the the comment I want the list of Comments to refresh displaying the newly added Comment.  Like So

[image]

Comment: is `ViewComments` another action in your controller?  what does it look like if so

Comment: Code is updated, its used to create the first partial view and provide the model for it.

Comment: do you have references to the jquery.unobtrusive libraries in your layout or view?.. you also need to make sure that `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` is set to true in your web.config

Comment: It is set to true in the web.config.  I have the libraries referenced in both of the partial views.

Comment: probably not good to have them in the partials.. you dont want to libraries to be references more than once.

Comment: Just move them to the main layout then?

Comment: i'd put them in the View

Comment: Will do.  So i guess the base question would be, am I able to access/update an element in the parent view from its 'grandchild' partial view?

Comment: i think so,  i just think  you might be trying to replace the wrong target somewhere.  you probably want the ajax option `InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace` also.. just hard to tell what might be going wrong with the snippets you posted

Comment: I can add more if needed.  I added the InsertionMode.  Now it seems to be trying to pass the stuff to the wrong view.  Instead of going through the parent view to update the partial, it is trying to return the partial and model from ViewComments to my AddComments partial.  If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

For now I have it changed.  I wanted to the comments section to be hidden until the show comments was clicked.  Then after posting a comment on the comments section was refreshed, but I couldn't get that to work.  So just reloading the whole page will refresh the comments section, but make it hidden at that time.  I made it so that the comments section shows by default without the option to hide it.  So unless anyone can figure out a way to get it to work how I wanted, this works for now.