# Autofill Textbox based on DropDownList

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

[MVC 4 Changing multiple display fields based on DropDownListFor selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31192524/mvc-4-changing-multiple-display-fields-based-on-dropdownlistfor-selection?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I'm trying to follow the above example but I think I'm having problems either with my javascript or my controller.

***JavaScript in View***

```
        $('#InstitutionDDL').change(function () {

        var institutionID = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Compendia/FillImplementationInfo?InstitutionID=' + institutionID,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: { InstitutionID: institutionID },

            success: function (ret) {
                $('#RegionImplementedField').val(ret.implementedRegion);
                $('#ProvinceImplementedField').val(ret.implementedProvince);
                $('#DistrictImplementedField').val(ret.implementedDistrict);
                $('#LocationImplementedField').val(ret.implementedLocation);
            },
            error: function (ex) {

            }
        });
        return false;

    });
```

***Controller Action***

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult FillImplementationInfo(int InstitutionID)
    {
        var ret = (from e in db.Institutions                     
                   where e.ID == InstitutionID
                   select new
                   {
                       implementedRegion = e.Province.Region.RegionName,
                       implementedProvince = e.Province.ProvinceName,
                       implementedDistrict = e.District,
                       implementedLocation = e.InstitutionAdress
                   }).FirstOrDefault();
        return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

***Source of DropDownList in View***

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InstitutionID, "Institution", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.InstitutionID, new SelectList(""), "--Select Institution--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id ="InstitutionDDL" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InstitutionID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

^from which after selecting, I want to pull all related data from connected tables using InstitutionID and put it in their respective textboxes known with IDs ending in #ImplementedField

***Debugging Results***

After selecting an option from the DropDownList, my script could capture the institutionID up to *$.ajax({ data: { InstitutionID: institutionID }*. However, it skips the *success: function(ret)* entirely and goes straight to *return false;* . Furthermore, the error that is being returned is 500 Internal Server Error, and based on the debugger, *ret* is being treated everywhere as undefined.  I've already tried modifying my controller and/or javascript multiple times but with no success. If I'm having a problem with my linq statement, I'm also posting here my Models. Apologies in advance for the long post, I really have no idea where I went wrong.

***Models***

```
public class Compendium
    {
        public int ID { get; set; } 
        public int InstitutionID { get; set; }
        public string RegionImplemented { get; set; }
        public string ProvinceImplemented { get; set; }
        public string DistrictImplemented { get; set; }
        public string LocationImplemented { get; set; }
        public virtual Institution Institution { get; set; }
    }

public class Institution
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ProvinceID { get; set; }
    public District? District { get; set; } //enum
    public virtual ICollection<Compendium> Compendia { get; set; }
    public virtual Province Province { get; set; }
}

public class Province
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int RegionID { get; set; }
        public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
        public string ProvinceName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Institution> Institutions { get; set; }
     }
```

Comment: Seems your AJAX URL is not in right way: `url: '/Compendia/FillImplementationInfo?InstitutionID=' + institutionID,`. Try using `url:  '/Compendia/FillImplementationInfo',` with same data & see what happens next.

Comment: Use your browser tools (the Network tab) to inspect the response which will give the details of the error. Also you can remome `contentType: 'application/json',` - your making a GET so its pointless, and adjust the url as noted by @TetsuyaYamamoto (your already adding it via the `data` option

Comment: Thanks for your time answering, unfortunately for me your suggestion didn't work in mine. Also I originally followed '@Url.Action("FillImplementationInfo", "Compendia")', but it also didn't work

Comment: Oh, I forgot to tell that you're using `[HttpGet]` attribute in controller action method but you're using `POST` method in AJAX call. Try changing to `[HttpPost]` in controller or `type: 'GET'` in AJAX and retry (I think the AJAX call cannot found action method marked with POST).

Comment: @Stephen noted, thanks. I took a look at Network and it seems my Controller Action FillImplementationInfo is returning a 404 error, I'm trying to focus on it now

Comment: Those suggests are not the source of the problem - just code improvements. Again **use your browser tools**! (the code in your method is throwing an exception

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Wow. It worked lol. Super thanks to both of you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this URL pattern with query string is not correct to initiate an AJAX call:

```
url: '/Compendia/FillImplementationInfo?InstitutionID=' + institutionID,
```

You need to change int Url.Action or simply remove query string on it:

```
url: '/Compendia/FillImplementationInfo',

// or
url: '@Url.Action("FillImplementationInfo", "Compendia")'
```

and then remove `contentType: 'application/json'` since the return type already declared as JSON with `dataType: 'json'`.

Second, as a general convention, the HTTP method used by jQuery AJAX call & the controller action method must be match to send the argument data successfully. In view side the AJAX call sent as POST method:

```
$.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           ...
      });
```

But the action method uses `HTTP GET`, which causes AJAX call cannot reach the action method since it only accepts `GET` request:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult FillImplementationInfo(int InstitutionID)
{
    ...
}
```

Note that you can use either GET or POST method with AJAX call, but ensure both of them are matched each other. Here is an example below:

**View (jQuery AJAX)**

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'GET', // ensure this HTTP method same as used by controller action method
          ...
      });
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult FillImplementationInfo(int InstitutionID)
{
    ...
}
```